# Return the greater numbers in a binary search tree in java

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I have this code where I am trying to print the greater numbers of a binary search tree. For example when I call the greater method greater(5) and my binary search tree has values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 I want to return the greater values from 5, so the outcome it will be 6,7,8,9,10. But my code has a problem and I don't know where is the problem. The system out should be return. It work with system out.

```
private int greater(BTNode<Integer> n,int nu)
{   int o=0;
    int leftAns = 0;
    if (n.left != null)
        leftAns = greaterInt(n.left, nu);
    int rightAns = 0;
    if (n.right != null)
        rightAns = greaterInt(n.right, nu);
    int answer = leftAns + rightAns;

    if (n.data.intValue() > nu){
        o+=n.data;
       System.out.println(n.data);
        //System.out.println(answer);
    }

   return o;
}
public int greater(int n)
{ if (root == null)
    return 0;
else
    return greaterInt(root,n);
}
```

Comment: For starters, your method returns an `int`, while it seems you want to return more than one value, so you'd probably need a `Collection<Integer>` as the return value (or one if its implementations)

Comment: I can not use Collection. I have to call the method many times in the public greater method and just print the values one under the other. For example 6/n 7/n 8/n (n=new line)

Comment: OK, and what's not working?

Comment: I have to use return instead of system out

Comment: in the private greater method

Comment: Do you want to `return` all greater numbers (then you need something like a collection or an array)? Or do you *only* want to *print* them as soon as each of them is found?

Comment: And do you really need `greater()` to return an `int`, or can it be a `void`?

Comment: I only want to print them as soon as each of them is found and i want the greater() not to be void! :)

Comment: ..............and void

Comment: So, where do you want to print them? Inside the `greater` method or from a method calling `greater`? BTW edit your comments instead of posting like this was an SMS chat ;)

Comment: I tried but it was printing me an error :P (for editing comment) in a main when calling the public greater method

Answer (score 1):

You have more values not only one; so just add those values in a list

```
private void greater(BTNode<Integer> n, int nu, List<Integer> integers) {
    if (n.left != null)
         greaterInt(n.left, nu);
    if (n.right != null)
        greaterInt(n.right, nu);
    if (n.data.intValue() > nu) {
        //System.out.println(n.data);
        //System.out.println(answer);
        integers.add(n.data);
    }
}

public List<Integer> greater(int n) {
    if (root == null)
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    List<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>();
    greaterInt(root, n, ar);
    return ar; 
}
```

If you want the sum of elements greater than n as your source looks like:

```
private int sum(BTNode<Integer> n, int nu) {
    int leftAns = 0;
    int rightAns = 0;

    if (n.left != null)
        leftAns = greaterInt(n.left, nu);
    if (n.right != null)
        rightAns = greaterInt(n.right, nu);
    if (n.data.intValue() > nu) {
        //System.out.println(n.data);
        //System.out.println(answer);
        return leftAns + rightAns + n.data;
    }
    return leftAns + rightAns;

}

public int sum(int n) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    else {
        return sum(root, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make and an nth(int n) method where is returns you the element that is in that position? (n position)

Comment: @user3310040 probably I can but this is a different question

Answer (score 0):

```
T max = null;

if(rootNode.getRightChild() == null){

max = rootNode.getData();

}

else{

maxItem(rootNode.getRightChild());

}

return max;
```

Comment: what is T? can I use int instead?